# Make dynamic method calls using NoMethodError handler instead of method_missing

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to make an API for dynamic reloading processes; right now I'm at the point where I want to provide in all contexts a method called `reload!`, however, I'm implementing this method on an object that has some state (so it can't be on Kernel).

Suppose we have something like

```
WorkerForker.run_in_worker do
  # some code over here...
  reload! if some_condition
end
```

Inside the `run_in_worker` method there is a code like the following:

```
begin
  worker = Worker.new(pid, stream)
  block.call
rescue NoMethodError => e
  if (e.message =~ /reload!/) 
    puts "reload! was called"
    worker.reload! 
  else
    raise e
  end
end
```

So I'm doing it this way because I want to make the `reload!` method available in any nested context, and I don't wanna mess the block I'm receiving with an `instance_eval` on the `worker` instance.

So my question is, is there any complications regarding this approach? I don't know if anybody has done this already (haven't read that much code yet), and if it has been done already? Is there a better way to achieve the objective of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming i understand you now, how about this:

```
my_object = Blah.new
Object.send(:define_method, :reload!) { 
    my_object.reload!
    ...
}
```

Using this method every object that invokes the `reload!` method is modifying the same shared state since `my_object` is captured by the block passed to `define_method`

Comment: Great... the use of closures on the `reload!` method is a really elegant way to solve this problem, thanks banister.

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with doing this?

```
def run_in_worker(&block)
    ...
    worker = Worker.new(pid, stream)
    block.call(worker)
end

WorkerForker.run_in_worker do |worker|
    worker.reload! if some_condition
end
```

Comment: Suppose I'm invoking methods from some other classes (like a framework), do you think is actually a good idea to pass around the worker through all the stack?... that was my first implementation until I realized that problem, thanks for your answer though

Comment: I don't see how that's a problem, in fact i don't even know what you mean :).

Comment: Okay, let me explain myself a bit better, Suppose you want to invoke the `reload!` method in any place (like you would do when a method is part of the Kernel module). At the same time, imagine that the block that `run_in_worker` receives, we invoke a method on a class, that at the same time invokes several methods in other classes and so on. Don't you think is a bit overkilling to pass the worker instance through all this different methods as a parameter just to invoke `worker.reload!`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want every method to know about an object without the method or the method's owner having been told about it. The way to accomplish this is a global variable. It's not generally considered a good idea (because it leads to concurrency issues, ownership issues, makes unit testing harder, etc.), but if that's what you want, there it is.

Comment: mightn't another approach, to avoid using globals, be to create the method using `define_method` and close over the object that needs to be shared between instances